# Given a derivative in some direction, calculate the normal derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Suppose $S(u,v,w=0)$ is a surface in $\mathbb R^3$, $\vec p(u,v)$ is a unit vector field, and $f(u,v,w)$ is some smooth enough scalar-valued function. The directional (“oblique”) derivative $\nabla_{\vec p}f(u,v,w)$ is known for all $u$, $v$, and $w \geq 0$. Is there any way to find the *normal* derivative of $f$ at $S$, i.e. $\nabla_{\vec n}f(u,v,0)$, without calculating the gradient $\nabla f(u,v,0)$?

Comment: No; this isn't enough data. If for instance the vector field is tangent to the surface this gives no information about the normal derivative.

Comment: Thank you, Chris. Your argument saved me a lot of time.